# Job queuing library/software for Java

Tags: java

The premise is this: For asynchronous job processing I have a homemade framework that:

- Stores jobs in database
- Has a simple java api to create more jobs and processors for them
- Processing can be embedded in a web application or can run by itself in on different machines for scaling out
- Web UI for monitoring the queue and canceling queue items

I would like to replace this with some ready made library because I would expect more robustness from those and I don't want to maintain this. I've been researching the issue and figured you could use JMS for something similar. But I would still have to build a simple java API, figure out a runtime where I would put the processing when I want to scale out and build a monitoring UI. I feel like the only thing I would benefit from JMS is that I would not have to do is the database stuff.

Is there something similar to this that is ready made?

**UPDATE**

Basically this is the setup I would want to do:

- Web application runs in a Servlet container or Application Server
- Web application uses a client api to create jobs
- X amount of machines process those jobs
- Monitor and manage jobs from an UI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Quartz:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: Seems like it can be clustered using a database to store the jobs. What I don't get is how I would build those cluster instances. Do I still have to code my own server that that keeps the Quartz running?

Comment: @palto Refer here http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/overview/features. You can embed quartz to your JSE or JEE application or instantiate quartz within app server (or servlet container).

Comment: But what if I want to scale out? I can run Quartz on the same machine that my web application runs(servlet container). But if I want to move job processing out of the web application and instantiate x amount of machines to process the jobs, how would I do that? Would I need to write my own server?

Comment: @palto Refer to link I have posted in previous comment. Quartz can be instantiated as a cluster of stand-alone programs. Final configuration depends on your requirements. Quartz by itself only provides API for you, and does not require specific environment, your jobs do. If your jobs are supposed to do for example transactional batch persistence, I think you will make a service archive and will deploy to application server with JPA/JTA implementation (JBoss AS for example).

Comment: I tried the samples in there and for clustering they had made their own public static void main to run the instances. I'd rather not invent that wheel again. I'd rather run it in ready made runtime. I'll check if Jboss could fit my needs with this.

Also for monitoring it seems like there is Quartz Manager software available, so it would solve my management needs.

Comment: According to the documentation of Quartz it is not a job queue: _"Quartz is not a job queue, although it is often used as one, and can do a reasonable job of such at a small scale."_ [Source](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.2/html/qtz-all/#page/quartz-scheduler-webhelp%2Fco-faq_general_questions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Spring Batch.

Link to sprint batch website: http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/

Comment: How would you setup spring batch to run in a setup where web application creates jobs and other machines process those jobs? I took a quick glance at the documentation and Spring Batch seems like it's for processing jobs like an ESB, but how would I use it to scale out?

Comment: I don't think Spring Batch has anything to do with ESB.  What does "scale it out" mean?  Sounds like a meaningless requirement to me, like deriding a solution because "it's not lightweight".  Can you explain?

Comment: By scale out I mean how would I add additional machines to process the  jobs.

Comment: What's that got to do with an ESB?

Comment: Nothing. You asked what I meant by scaling out and I answered you.